# Issue in Passing data from one goroutine to another using channel

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I have developed the following:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "time"

func add ( n int){
    
    ch :=make(chan int)
    sum :=0
    for i:= 0;i<n;i++{
        sum = sum+i
    }
    
    ch <- sum
    fmt.Println("Sum is",sum)
    
    
}

func display(ch1 chan int){
    
    fmt.Println("Sum is now",ch1)

}
func main() {

  ch2 :=make(chan int)
  go add(10)
  go display(ch2)
  fmt.Println("Hello World!")
  time.Sleep(time.Second)

}
```

I want to pass the current sum to the function display.
But, when I am printing the sum I get the below message in the console:

Hello World!
Sum is now 0xc000094060

Please, Help in printing the current sum.

Comment: You are printing the channel, not the data you read from the channel, `fmt.Pritln("...",<-ch1)`

Comment: also keep in mind that as it stands right now there is no guarantee that display() will run after add().

Comment: Additionally, `add` creates `ch` in its own scope.  Nothing else can access `add`'s `ch`, so `ch <- sum` is never going to complete.  You need to create a channel, *pass it* to `add`, and then read from the same channel in `display`.  There's no reason for `display` to be run in a goroutine.  Hint: if you're doing concurrent programming and you are tempted to put in a `time.Sleep` that means you're not synchronizing properly

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing the value from channel, you print the channel!
try:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "time"

func add (ch chan int, n int){

    sum :=0
    for i:= 0;i<n;i++{
        sum = sum+i
    }

    ch <- sum
    fmt.Println("Sum is",sum)


}

func display(ch chan int){
    fmt.Println("Sum is now", <-ch)
}

func main() {

    ch :=make(chan int)
    go add(ch, 10)
    go display(ch)
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

}
```

Also, why run display in a goroutine?
If you do something complex in add and it takes longer than 1 Second this application will just stop and do nothing. Maybe take a look at waitgroups.